# Where are the log files located for Hadoop mapreduce job run from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

When I run wordcount job from eclipse as a hadoop project, I cannot find the location for the log files. My job name is job_local_0001. Where are the jobtracker log files. My log files in hadoop/logs directory do not contain the information when I run a job through eclipse. Help!